# Counting the number of matchings in a complete bipartite graph

Tags: assignment-problem, matching

I am trying to count the number of matchings in a complete bipartite graph (perfect as well as imperfect). It's relatively easy for me to convince myself that there is $n!$ *perfect* matchings in the graph $\mathcal{K}_{n,n}$. However, I cannot seem to figure out how many matchings this graph contains. I have experimented a bit, and the number seems to be very large.
I have repeatedly solved the IP
\begin{align}
  \min &\ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij }\\
  \mbox{s.t.:}\ & \sum_{i =1}^n x_{ij}=1,&&\forall j=1,\dots,n\\
              \ & x_{ij}\in\{0,1\},&&\forall i,j=1,\dots,n
\end{align}
and then added ``no-good'' inequalities to remove the current solution until the solver (CPLEX) declared the problem infeasible. For $n=1,2,3,4$ I have gotten the numbers $1,4,27,256$ which suggests that the number of matchings should be $n^n$. But $n=5$ gave me $3174$ matchings (not the expected $5^5=3125$).

Can anyone guide me to the number of mathings in $\mathcal{K}_{n,n}$?

---

Edit: The no-good inequalities I use are the following
\begin{equation}
\sum_{(i,j):\bar{x}_{ij}=1}x_{ij}\leq n-1
\end{equation}
where $\bar{x}$ is the solution I want to cut out.

It turns out that @Kuifje was right and that I had a bug in my code. After fixing that, I get that there is $n^n$ solutions to my IP.

Comment: Can you include the no-good cut that you use?

Comment: To get a valid matching, shouldn't you constraint $\sum_j x_{ij} \le 1$ for all $i$ (no repetitions of left endpoint)? Also, by making your constraint equality rather than inequality, aren't you skipping (imperfect) matchings that miss some right endpoints?

Comment: @prubin obviously I'm using the wrong terminology. The IP is the corret one, so maybe what I am counting is the number of semi-assignments. The idea is to count how many ways $n$ jobs can be assigned to $n$ agents if each agent in principle can handle all items, and all items need to be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the bipartite graph is $K_{n,n}$, then all $n$ vertices of the left hand size have exactly $n$ possible matches (each node of the right layer is a candidate). So the total number of matchings is $n^n$ indeed.

Maybe you can try and detect if there are identical matchings among the $3174$ found by CPLEX ?

Comment: You count infeasible matchings (meaning that a vertex can be covered by several edges) in your calculation. Lars brought some insights above.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for the clarification. I was just trying to match the OP's sequence and proposed LP. I think @prubin's comment sheds some light on the question which seems to be ill-posed.

Comment: you’re right. We probably should have commented and fixed the question itself first, before commenting and fixing answers.

Answer (score 8):

A matching of size $m$ in $\mathrm{K}_{n,n}$ is uniquely identified by (i) the set of covered vertices in the left partition, for which there are $\binom{n}{m}$ choices, (ii) the set of covered vertices in the right position, ditto $\binom{n}{m}$ choices, and (iii) a bijection from the covered vertices on the left onto the covered vertices on the right, for which there are $m!$ choices. This means there are $\binom{n}{m}^2 m!$ matchings of size $m$, and thus
$$
  \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}^2 m!
$$
matchings altogether. For example, for $n=2$ there are $7$ matchings: $2$ perfect matchings, $4$ matchings of size $1$ (choose one out of two vertices to match on each side), and $1$ empty matching. Small table:
$$
  \begin{array}{rr}
    n & \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}^2 m! \\
    1 & 2 \\
    2 & 7 \\
    3 & 34 \\
    4 & 209 \\
    5 & 1546 \\
    6 & 13327 \\
    7 & 130922
  \end{array}
$$

Comment: Welcome, @Lars H. +1  This is OEIS sequence [A002720](https://oeis.org/A002720).